# Yarn 2 init, add failing

Tags: yarn-v2

I'm experimenting with yarn 2 and faceplanting.

I created a new folder: `/projects/yarn2/`

As per their install guide https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started I ran

```
cd /projects/yarn2/
yarn set version berry
yarn init
```

then (as per their guide https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/usage )

`yarn add react`

and got the following error:

```
Usage Error: The nearest package directory (/projects/yarn2) doesn't seem to be part of the project declared in /projects.

- If the project directory is right, it might be that you forgot to list yarn2 as a workspace.
- If it isn't, it's likely because you have a yarn.lock or package.json file there, confusing the project root detection.

$ yarn add [--json] [-E,--exact] [-T,--tilde] [-C,--caret] [-D,--dev] [-P,--peer] [-O,--optional] [--prefer-dev] [-i,--interactive] [--cached] ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check to see if you have a `package.json` or `yarn.lock` file in your /projects directory.  If you do, clear it/them out and this should start working.

Comment: As per the docs, I should do this

1. yarn init,
2. yarn,
3. yarn install. 

If the next step (yarn/yarn install) would want me to delete the package.json or yarn.lock file, why would it make me create it in the first place by running yarn init?

Answer (score 36):

You either don't have package.json or yarn.lock which confuses yarn if the package is added in the workspace or not. Just run the following command and I think your problem must be solved.

> cd <folder_name>/<project_name>
>
> touch yarn.lock
>
> yarn

Comment: damn why cant yarn just look if .lock doesn't exist then create it like you did?

Comment: this never "confused" yarn before..

Comment: I had the same error with workspaces. I created a new workspace, `yarn init` ran, but `yarn add <...>` failed for new dependencies. Adding the `yarn.lock` file solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the previous answers what worked for me was:

It seems to be that yarn.lock file is what's really required, so if you have started with yarn v1.x and did yarn init - then you will have a `package.json` file in the project dir already.

If you now switch over to yarn v2 by doing `yarn set berry`, and want to add a package by yarn add [whatever] it will fail. You can work around that by creating an empty file by: `touch yarn.lock` (or on windows just `cat '' > yarn.lock`) after that it should work fine.

---

I figured out an even better / faster way to do it now, just do this in an empty project folder:
`yarn init -2`
this will initialize a new yarn v2 project folder with .yarnrc.yml, package.json, and the .yarn folder, also initializes an empty .git folder and adds a proper .gitignore. check by `yarn --version` - should echo v2.x.x

Comment: Thanks! I just ran into this bug, now I wonder that `yarn set berry` means lol

Answer (score 2):

**Usage Error**: The nearest package directory **(/<path_to_folder>/<project_name>)** doesn't seem to be part of the project declared in **/<path_to_folder>**.

**Solution**:
Search for **yarn.lock** and **package.json** files inside **/<path_to_folder>** and delete them!

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove yarn.lock and package.json file in your root directory ,some times there may be .yarnrc yarnyml files in you root directory you have to remove them also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if there is a package.json/yarn.lock file in the /project directory, I have had this problem before, and when I removed these files, my problem was solved.